# make chrome extension using nodejs

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, google-chrome-extension, google-api-nodejs-client

***Question Background***

> We are building Chrome Extension. and we need to get the python code in the process.

***What i know***

> 1. I know that python code can be imported using Node JS.
> 2. Node JS is used to create servers
> 3. Chrome extension is not building server, but making programs(maybe client?)

is it right?

***Question***

To achieve our goal

> 1. Do We need to create server with node js and communicate with chrome extension(using socket.io)?
> 2. Is there another way to apply node js in chrome extension?
> 3. Is there another way to get the python code into the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Chromium web extension code necessarily must be pure client-side Javascript structured to run in the [browser's extension environment](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/).  There's no support for nodejs or python in that environment; it's very constrained.  Because cybercreeps.

You can use XmlHttpRequest or fetch operations in your extension code to access web services.  Your extension manifest will need to [grant permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800988/using-jquery-ajax-in-a-google-chrome-extension) to access your server.

You can meet your requirement by building and hosting a server for your extension to use.  You can use nodejs and a framework like express and/or socket.io, or you can use python, [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and a framework like Flask or Django. If you build your server with python, it probably will perform better than a nodejs serves that [spawns child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to run python. It will definitely be easier to install, debug and maintain.

Comment: I GOT IT!! THANK YOU ~!~!~!~!